# cant write to log file from com visible .net class in asp web page

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com, server-side

I'm using a .net class as a registered com object that is being called from a classic asp web page on Microsoft Server 2003.  So given all these 'layers' I'm having trouble understanding the source of the problem.

The problem is I can't write to a text file.  In fact it's not even creating the file.  Not sure if this is a permissions issue or not.  The sub routine is below:

```
Private Sub OutputToLog(ByVal message As String, ByVal path As String)
    Dim sw As StreamWriter
    Try
        If File.Exists(path) = False Then
            sw = File.CreateText(path)
            sw.Write(Date.Now.ToString() + " - " + message + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
            sw.Close()
        Else
            sw = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(path))
            sw.Write(Date.Now.ToString() + " - " + message + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
            sw.Close()
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

What is preventing the file being created and written to?

Comment: What user is being impersonated for your ASP page?  What is `path` and what permissions does it have?

Comment: I think a generic web user.  That's probably the issue.  Will test this out soon.